# Reading a video file VideoCapture

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Why is it if i read a video file using cv2.VideoCapture('video.avi') the fps is very very very low? I want the fps to be the same as when i play the video using a video player(30fps). What changes should i make to achieve this? Btw, i am using a raspberry pi 3 with python.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Fchecking.avi')
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)

while(1):

    # Take each frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    ret,mask = cv2.threshold(img2gray,140,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 
    w3w = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(mask,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,47,2)   
    cv2.imshow("mask", mask)

    mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(w3w) 

    img2_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask_inv)

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img2_fg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower_red= np.array([0,58,130])
    upper_red = np.array([255,255,255])

    erosion = cv2.erode(mask,kernel,iterations = 3)
    rmask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)


    mask2 = cv2.morphologyEx(rmask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    final = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask2)
    cv2.imshow('final',final)
    cv2.imshow('original',frame)


    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I guess that's a little too much workload for the poor little RPi. Even my desktop machine has a hard time processing your while loop. Are you asking how to optimize your code? For starters, try commenting out 'erosion = cv2.erode(..)' as the result of this function is never used...

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it if i read a video file using cv2.VideoCapture('video.avi') the fps is very very very low?

The answer to this question is the massive chunk of code that you have between reading the frame and showing it to the screen. When you watch the video in a standard video player it doesnt do this processing.

```
img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,mask = cv2.threshold(img2gray,140,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 
w3w = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(mask,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,47,2)   
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)

mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(w3w) 

img2_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask_inv)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img2_fg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_red= np.array([0,58,130])
upper_red = np.array([255,255,255])

erosion = cv2.erode(mask,kernel,iterations = 3)
rmask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)


mask2 = cv2.morphologyEx(rmask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
final = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask2)
```

> What changes should i make to achieve this?

It's likely that:

1. If you reduce the processing it will speed up
2. If you increase the processing power it will speed up